# Data node capacity increase is not detected by the HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a virtual hadoop cluster composed of 4 virtual machine (1 master and 3 slaves) and recently added 100GB capacity to my datanodes in cluster. The problem is that HDFS does not detect this increasing. I restart datanode, namenode and also format HDFS but didn't affect. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: By adding you mean what? Did you add the path of your Datanode directory to the hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: You don't need to format HDFS only to add a new datanode volume. You do need mount the volume in /etc/fstab and  edit the hdfs-site.xml on the datanode with the new mount point

Comment: @ cricket_007 There is not new Volume! There were a volume with 500GB and now 100GB is added to it. what should I mount in /etc/fstab when the volume does not change? (Don't forget that machines are virtual).

Comment: @ Abhinav, "Add" means Increase. Yes, I had added the path of datanode directory in property "dfs.datanode.data.dir". Now, there isn't new directory. I've just changed size of the volume. The problem is HDFS can not detect this increasing and the capacity remains on the same previous value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing the steps to **add datanode/increase hdfs volume size**:

- Create a folder in the root eg. `/hdfsdata`
- Create a folder under home eg. `/home/hdfsdata`
- Provide permission to 'hdfs' user to this folder: `chown hdfs:hadoop -R /home/hdfsdata`
- Provide file/folder permissions to this folder: `chmod 777 -R /home/hdfsdata.`
- Mount this new folder: `mount --bind /home/hdfsdata/ /hdfsdata/`
- At last, add this newly created directory to the hdfs-site.xml under the property "dfs.datanode.data.dir" with a comma separated value.

When i cd to /hadoop/hdfs/data

After the above steps, **restart the HDFS service** and you have your capacity increased.

Comment: I did all the steps, but capacity did not change

Comment: Is there any particular error? Are you using HDP od CDH?

Comment: An edit to comment above: When I added the path (/home/hdfsdata) to property "dfs.datanode.data.dir", 20GB is added to capacity of datanode. but why 20 GB? I use apache hadoop distribution.

Comment: How much memory do you expect to be added? And the folder you added to datanode, check the size of that particular folder using 'df or du' command.

Comment: I added 100GB, So I expect 100GB added to HDFS. I checked size of directory and that was 20GB! but I have 100GB free on the disk. Should I increase the size of directory?

Comment: Exactly man! Because you added the directory to your Hdfs. So, it will consider the size of your directory only, not the space of the entire disk.

Comment: Accept the answer if you don't have any further queries. So that the topic can be closed.

Comment: In windows, we don't need to increase size of a directory and it can grow as much as size of a drive. I don't have much experience with Linux and I should look for the answer to my new question. Please edit your answer and include the step of adding the path to the hdfs-site.xml file for accepting.

Comment: Done, I can't answer your another query here. So, you can close this topic and ask another question regarding the size increment of your directory in Linux